# How do I upgrade my sword at the Sorceress Hut?

Tags: candy-box

In Candy Box, I have a diamond sword and 80,000 lollipops, but there is no "Sword, better sword" option. What do I have to do to get that option?

Answer (score 15):

You need to sharpen your sword with candy dust, enhance it by getting chocolate from the frog, and then enchant it in the forge. After that, you can have a better sword.